# Disable SSL mode in a ruby on rails application

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ssl, ubuntu-16.04

I am running a ruby on rails application in a docker container running Ubuntu 16. I have installed mysql 5.7 which is the compatible version available on ubuntu 16.

Mysql 5.7 trues to connect over ssl by default and I see the SSL error when I run the rails server

I tried to disable SSL in the following ways

In the /etc/mysql/my.cnf

```
[client]
sslmode = DISABLED
```

In the database yml file

```
sslmode: DISABLED
sslmode: "DISABLED"
```

How can I disable the default ssl communication?

What I am trying to achieve is the equivalent of

```
mysql -h "host" -u "user --ssl-mode=disables
```

Comment: Do you mean SSL for the database or SSL for your web site over HTTPS?

Comment: For the database.

Answer (score 4):

The correct `database.yml` config line is `ssl_mode`:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: true
  database: [database name]
  pool: 5
  username: [your username]
  password: [your password]
  host: [host name]
  ssl_mode: disabled
```

Answer (score 1):

To disable the Open SSL just include/change the following mode

```
OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
```

or try this

```
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
```

> Note: This also possesses threats by accepting invalid certificates.

After the testing phase, to ensure that SSL verification happens again later on use the following mode:

```
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
```

Comment: Hello - I am looking for the database communication being unsecured. I was hoping the config is in the database yml